# How to do a curl GET request

Tags: php, curl

I have a header redirection code

```
Header (Location:"http://www.foo.com/x.php?name=".$name."&mob=".$mobNo);
```

BUt how to do the same using cURL?How to echo the response ?Please help

Answer (score 1):

http://codular.com/curl-with-php

Here is a tutorial on how to use curl with PHP

```
<?php 
  $c = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http//whateverUrl.com');
 or 
  $c = curl_init('http//whateverUrl.com');


  $response = curl_exec($c);
  curl_close($c);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_URL => sprintf('http://www.foo.com/x.php?name=%s&mob=%s', $name, $mobNo), 
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [curl_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) method to retrieve it using cURL.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.foo.com/x.php?name=".$name."&mob=".$mobNo);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// Retrieve it
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```